# What is the latest version of R known to run on windows xp?

Tags: r, windows, windows-xp

As in R documentation:

> The last version known to run on Windows 2000 was 2.12.2. Windows XP is no longer supported.

I tried to install R 3.4.3 on windows xp , but i faced problems when installing packages that i didn't face when installing them on Windows 7 system. I think it is safe to assume that R 2.12.2 runs on Windows xp as windows 2000, but does a version later than R 2.12.2 runs on windows xp also? what is the highest version ?

Comment: Try which version of Rtools is the newest that works. The highest R version that doesn't require a newer Rtools version should be the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version officially supported on XP was one version below, 3.4.2. Nevertheless, R as high as 3.6.0 installs and runs well on XP (though is not officially QA tested).

Starting from v.3.6.1, R is packed with InnoSetup v.6.0.0 (that means, installing on WinXP will not succeed and end up with an error "not valid Win32 application"). However, one may try to unpack the installer and deploy the files manually (still may help to launch R itself). Another option which may be useful is One Core API.

But... All this stuff is relevant if one is going to use plain R or integrated R environment in some old application. Many 3rd-party R packages require the most up-to-date versions of R, what will cause inconveniences on WinXP.

Comment: It is tough to give up on old, working equipment. R wasn't contemplated when CPM was around.

Comment: Greetings! This answer doesn't really provide much supporting information to be helpful. Please provide more substantive answers to questions next time.

Comment: Okay, okay, I am editing my reply now that I have got myself not-so-helpful. Addi :)

Comment: Presumably one should also be able to install old versions of packages (find the URL for the archived package and use `install.packages(<url>, repos = "none")`)